# Neo4j CYPHER node_auto_index for range lookup

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I'd like to know if there's any way how to use auto indexing for range lookup. If I query something like

`START age=node:node_auto_index(age<20 and age>10)
 RETURN age;`

it returns

```
Exception in thread "main" string literal or parameter expected.
```

I also tried something like

```
START age=node:node_auto_index(age = range(10,20)) 
RETURN age;
```

but it looks like it needs just `age = "15"` or something like that.

Any ideas what to do please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Range%20Searches) states that the range syntax is as follows:

```
age:[10 TO 20]
```

The resulting query (but haven't tested this):

```
START age=node:node_auto_index("age:[10 TO 20]") 
RETURN age;
```

The following read might also be interesting for you: [Range queries in Neo4j using Lucene query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049029/range-queries-in-neo4j-using-lucene-query-syntax)

EDIT: not sure if it will work for you; check out this [github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/485).

Comment: Thanks, syntax is ok now, but it returns no result, even if I have just 1 node with appropriate age created.

Comment: Ceck out the github issue. It's probably exactly what you are experiencing.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'd be interesting to see your solution. Also feel free to approve this answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I managed that via Java API, where I used `QueryContext.numericRange(property_name,from,to)
QueryContext.numericRange(age,10,20)` querying, as written here http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-lucene-extras.html#indexing-lucene-numeric-ranges

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use where clause, something like below?

```
START node=node:node_auto_index(name='PersonName') 
where node.age > 20 and node.age <20
RETURN node.age;
```

Comment: Should be `START node:node(*)`.

Comment: But then it doesn't use indexing, which I need to use, does it?

Comment: Indeed, but this could be your last resort. :-)

Comment: START node=node:node_auto_index(name="startNodeName") 
where node.age > 20 and node.age <20
RETURN node.age;

Comment: name - can be any indexed property of the node, and is value could be any starting point value.

Answer (score 0):

Following a workshop with Stefan Armbruster from Neo4J Technologies the same topic came up.

The most basic solution we came up with was to make sure that all the values stored for the numeric property has the same length. Thus, one will need to pad the age property values as follows, 011, 099, 103... And the values are stored as strings not numeric values.

Doing this everything should work from the index.